# GPS coordinates are not matching up with street network shapefile despite having same projection

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, gps

As some background, my colleagues and I used a shapefile of a city's streets as a reference to collect GPS data. They were written simply with a field for: street name, lat, and long. The many points make when looked at do seem to match to mirror the street network so I don't think the GPS is off.

However, I need to overlay the original street network shapefile with these new GPS points. The problem is that they are a bit far off from one another on the basemap despite having the same projected coordinate system. What I did was just adding the .csv file with the coordinates of each point to the map as XY data. According to these coordinates, the thousands of GPS data points are about a few hundred miles off from where the original street network layer is on the map. I'm sure this is an issue with projection, but I've been trying to troubleshoot it for an hour and haven't managed to get them to line up or even move.

I have checked the source and they are both the same. I have tried batch projecting them as well, but it just results in duplicates being placed upon each of the shapefiles.

Here are the contents of the Data Source of each layer.
GPS:

```
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile: path\to\data
Geometry Type:  Point
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No 

Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_StatePlane_Illinois_East_FIPS_1201_Feet
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  984250.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -88.33333333
Scale_Factor:   0.99997500
Latitude_Of_Origin: 36.66666667
Linear Unit:    Foot_US

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Street Network

```
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile:  \path\to\file
Geometry Type:  Line
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No 

Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_StatePlane_Illinois_East_FIPS_1201_Feet
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  984250.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -88.33333333
Scale_Factor:   0.99997500
Latitude_Of_Origin: 36.66666667
Linear Unit:    Foot_US

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

I'm pretty new to GIS, so I'm hoping it may be something simple. Does anyone know of any way I could overlay these two layers? Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: try assigning your gps data WGS84 (don't reproject, just reassign) and see if they line up.  GPS devices usually use the WGS84 datum.

Comment: Thanks for replying jbalk. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how would I go about reassigning the gps data to WGS84? I have only been reprojecting and have been looking around and haven't found another way to change it.

Comment: what software buddy?

Comment: In QGIS it's in the vector general tools and is called 'Assign Projection'.  In ArcMap it's called 'define projection'

Comment: ARCMap 10.5.1 is what I am currently using for this project :)

Comment: Data Management Tools > Projections and Transformations > Define Projection

Comment: If you3 GPS points are 1-10m out of whack, that's a poor GPS unit; if they're 1km out of whack, it's likely a datum issue. But if they're 100mi off, then that's user error. If you start over and document all your steps, then if it still doesn't work, you can post your procedure. Remember: Define Projection is for data without a .prj; everything else should be Project.

Comment: What is the first thing you add this to ArcMap 10.5.1 ? Is it on the projection on the fly ?